# MATLAB Index out of bounds error with `gradient` function

Tags: matlab, math, format, gradient

I have 3 arrays, in one dimensional problem

```
A, B, C = arrays (1-100)
```

1-D mesh , distance between grid-points = a

I need to write in Matlab code the next mathematical expression:

```
E = A^(-1/3) * ( D/Dx (B * ((DC/Dx)^(1/3)) )
```

I wrote it as:

```
DCDx   =  gradient(C, a);
e1     =  B * ( DCDx ^ (1/3) );
e2     =  gradient(e1 , a);
E      =  A^(-1/3) * e2;
```

EDIT :

```
for i:length(B)
    DCDx   =  gradient(C, a);
    e1     =  B.* ( Root(DCDx) );
    e2     =  gradient(e1 , a);
    E      =  ( Root(A) )^(-1).* e2;
end

where Root, is my function

function X = Root(X)
X = nthroot(X,3)

unfortunately still is not working. 
error = "Matrix dimensions must agree."

any idea?
```

Comment: This is most likely a problem with using `*` [(matrix multiply)](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mtimes.html) when you mean `.*` [(element-wise multiplication)](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/times.html).

Comment: new error
    
    "Matrix dimensions must agree." ( e1 =  B.* ( DCDx ^ (1/3) ) ; )
    
    thank you for your help about .* , but still I get an error. 
    Even the C is an array (1-100), 100 rows - one column, the DCDx is not. 
    Any idea how to overcome this?

Comment: Try using an element-wise power as well, `DCDx .^ (1/3)`.

Comment: thanks, but I can not do that. I explain above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this code work as you would like? I don't understand what you are using the loop for.

```
DCDx = gradient(C, a);
e1 = B .* nthroot(DCDx , 3);
e2 = gradient(e1 , a);
E = e2 ./ nthroot(A , 3);
```

I am using the following vectors to test the code:

```
A=rand(100,1);
B=rand(100,1);
C=rand(100,1);
a=.1;
```

Comment: I want to calculate the E array. A, B, C are arrays, 100 rows, 1 column. I do not know if the use of for loop is the right one. I tried to use E(i), e1(i), e2(i), but I can not cause of the gradient function.

Comment: I tested this code with 3 random 100x1 matrices for `A`, `B` and `C`, and got `E` as a 100x1 matrix. What is the problem or error with my answer?

Comment: e1 = B .* nthroot(DCDx , 3);
"Error using ==> times Matrix dimensions must agree."

Comment: That's odd, I can't reproduce the error. I will modify my answer to include the vectors I am using to test it, maybe you will spot something wrong.

Comment: I think that the error in my code is the calculation of C. I am checking now. Might the format is wrong.

Comment: Thank you for all your help! My mistake was that the calculation of C in previous step was (1,100) not (100,1). Also, I use for loop for these calculations, which seems not to be the best technique? or not?